# in powershell, [Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase -bor [Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Multiline

Tags: powershell

Trying to take a vhdl or ada source file, match the keywords, and replace them with keywords in the list.  However, my regex isn't work with ignorecase and multiline, subsituting of $1 and $2.
Here's my code below.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

$script:regop_gi = [Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase -bor [Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Multiline

function ReplaceKeyWords {
    param(
        [string]$text, 
        [string[]]$keywords
    ) #returns string
    
    for ($k = 0; $k -lt $keywords.Length; $k++) {
        $r0 = "([^a-zA-Z0-9_@]|^)" + $keywords[$k] + "([^a-zA-Z0-9_]|$)"
        $r1 = [regex]::new($r0, $script:regop_gi)
        $text = $text.replace($r1, "$1" + $keywords[$k] + "$2")
    }

    return $text
}


$vhdl = @()
$vhdl += "library ieee;"
$vhdl += "use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;"
$vhdl += "   use std.textio.all;"
$vhdl += ""
$vhdl += ""
$vhdl += "entity mydesign is"
$vhdl += "    port("
$vhdl += "      clk:in std_logic;"
$vhdl += "  rst:in std_logic;"
$vhdl += "         xyz  : in    std_logic_vector(7 downo 0);"
$vhdl += "   abc:out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)"
$vhdl += "    )"
$vhdl += "end entity"
$vhdl += ""
$vhdl += "architecture beh of mydesign is"
$vhdl += "begin"
$vhdl += "    process(clk,           rst)"
$vhdl += "  begin"
$vhdl += "        if (rst) then"
$vhdl += "           abc        <=             (others=>'0');"
$vhdl += " else (rising_edge(clk)) then"
$vhdl += "    abc        <=             xyz;"
$vhdl += "       end if;"
$vhdl += "                  end process;"
$vhdl += "end architecture;"
$vhdl += ""

$vhdl_lines = $vhdl -join "`n"


$KeyWords = @(
    "BEGIN"
    "END"
    "ENTITY"
    "ARCHITECTURE"
)

$newtext = ReplaceKeyWords -text $vhdl_lines -keywords $Keywords

write-host $newtext
```

Answer (score 1):

The following statement is wrong on multiple levels:

> `$text = $text.replace($r1, "$1" + $keywords[$k] + "$2")`

- Given that `$text` is of type `[string]`, `.replace()` refers to the [`System.String.Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.Replace) method, which operates on *verbatim* strings, not on *regexes*.
- Using an expandable (interpolating) strings such as `"$1"` and `"$2"` causes `$1` and `$2` to be interpreted a *PowerShell variable references*.

---

You were probably looking for the following, using the [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator:

```
$text = $text -replace ('\b{0}\b' -f $keywords[$k]), $keywords[$k]
```

PowerShell's regex operations are case-insensitive *by default*, and, given that your replacements do not *straddle lines*, neither the `IgnoreCase` nor the `MultiLine` regex options are needed.

---

Also, in PowerShell (Core) 7+, you can simplify your code as follows, taking advantage of being able to pass a *script block* as the replacement operand:

```
# Use a here-string to define your string.
$vhdl_lines = @'
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
   use std.textio.all;


entity mydesign is
    port(
      clk:in std_logic;
  rst:in std_logic;
         xyz  : in    std_logic_vector(7 downo 0);
   abc:out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
    )
end entity

architecture beh of mydesign is
begin
    process(clk,           rst)
  begin
        if (rst) then
           abc        <=             (others=>'0');
 else (rising_edge(clk)) then
    abc        <=             xyz;
       end if;
                  end process;
end architecture;
'@

# The array of keywords to upper-case.
$keyWords = @(
    "BEGIN"
    "END"
    "ENTITY"
    "ARCHITECTURE"
)

# Replace the keywords with their uppercase versions.
$vhdl_lines -replace ('\b(?:{0})\b' -f ($keyWords -join '|')),
                     { $_.Value.ToUpper() }
```